# Reload data from database without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My Ajax successfully update some information in database and as a result he should update one element, which shows this information. But it doesn't. However, after refreshing page, which cause reconnecting to db, information updating. Here is the function:

```
function topUpTheBalance(){
        var d = document.getElementById("numberForm").value;
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handler.php',
        data: {
            'topUpBalance':d,
        },
        success: function () {
            var k = document.getElementById("balanceNumber");
            k.innerHTML ="Your balance: "+ <?php echo $userRow['userBalance']; ?>;
        }
        }
        );
    }
```

and the handler.php

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
     exit;
    }
    $res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    //$link =  mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password", "users");
    $bal = $userRow['userBalance']+$_POST['topUpBalance'];
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE users SET userBalance = ? WHERE userId = ?")){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "di", $bal, $userRow['userId']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to update this information without refreshing the page?

Comment: Where is the call? Where is balanceNumber

Comment: it call from the button in html. HTML file is quite large, so I didn't want to add it here. But as I said, ajax makes his work, but he can't refresh data as it wasn't updated on the page

Comment: I see no button in your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You would need to collect `data` back from your PHP Script to reflect that data and add it to your DOM. Also your example does not contain enough detail to help very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to run php in the client side when you wrote k.innerHTML="string"+php code
You should instead produce an output in the php file you request to and retrieve that output and put it in here.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp
The link explains how to send data to server through POST and get data from server through GET.

Answer (score 0):

there is no detail information to help you but the first thing i noticed is your AJAX call, to get data you need to call it through GET type:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'getdata.php', 
    'type': 'GET',
    'dataType': 'json', 
    'data': {'topUpBalance':d}, 
    'success': function(data) {
      // if the request calls properly
    },
    'error': function(data) {
      // if the request fails.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is you should throw output from php side but you have not sent output and You should use isset($_POST['topUpBalance']) and then go to other process for example :-

```
if(isset($_POST['topUpBalance'])){
     $res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
     userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
     $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $bal = $userRow['userBalance'] + $_POST['topUpBalance'];

   if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE users SET userBalance = ? 
     WHERE userId = ?")){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "di", $bal, $userRow['userId']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);
       //Send output echo ...... ;
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      }
       mysqli_close($link);
}
```

In jquery side :-
receive data using parameter

```
function topUpTheBalance(){
    var d = document.getElementById("numberForm").value;
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'handler.php',
    data: {
        'topUpBalance':d,
    },
    success: function (data) {
     // use sent data or unsent data for processing  
    }
    }
    );
}
```